# Mysql doesn't recognize proper execution plan

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm building a stored procedure for an ETL. With in the stored proc a table is created and the same table is used in the next query as two instances(using the same table with two aliases). Since the second query takes absurd amount of time I looked at the execution plans and executed the queries without the stored proc. When executed without the stored proc second query runs as expected in a reasonable amount of time.

Here are the two queries.

Query_1:

```
CREATE TABLE TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BDM_$tblname (
    SALE_JOURNAL_ID BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    DISPLAY_ORDER INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX IDX_SALE_JOURNAL_ID (SALE_JOURNAL_ID),
    INDEX IDX_DEBCONS_ID (DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID),
    INDEX IDX_DISPLAY_ORDER (DISPLAY_ORDER)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BDM_$tblname
    SELECT DISTINCT
        TSS.SALE_JOURNAL_ID,
        RDC.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID,
        RDC.DISPLAY_ORDER
    FROM
        TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BOOKING_$tblname TSS

        LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING RB
            ON (RB.BOOKING_ID = TSS.BOOKING_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING_DEPT_LEVELS BDL
            ON (BDL.BOOKING_ID = RB.BOOKING_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TMPRPT_STBDEX_SEGMENT_$tblname RS
            ON (RS.SEGMENT_ID = TSS.SEGMENT_ID)

        LEFT OUTER JOIN DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP RDC
            ON (RDC.DEBTOR_ID = RB.DEBTOR_ID AND
                RDC.CONSULTANT_ID IS NOT NULL AND
                RDC.CONSULTANT_TYPE_CODE = 'BUSINESS_DEVELOPMENT' AND
                RDC.COMMISSION_PERCENTAGE IS NOT NULL AND
                (RDC.DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL_CODE = 'BOTH' OR CASE WHEN RDC.DOMESTIC_INTERNATIONAL_CODE = 'DOMESTIC' THEN 1 = RS.IDT_NUMBER ELSE 1 <> RS.IDT_NUMBER END ) AND
                RDC.START_DATE <= TSS.TRANSACTION_DATE AND
                (RDC.FINISH_DATE IS NULL OR RDC.FINISH_DATE >= TSS.TRANSACTION_DATE))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN COST_CENTRE_DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP CCDCR
            ON (CCDCR.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID = RDC.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID AND CCDCR.COST_CENTRE_ID = RB.COST_CENTRE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENT_DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP DDCR
            ON (DDCR.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID = RDC.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID AND
                (DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDL.LEVEL0 OR 
                DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDL.LEVEL1 OR
                DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDL.LEVEL2 OR
                DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDL.LEVEL3 OR
                DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDL.LEVEL4 OR
                DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID = BDL.LEVEL5))
    WHERE
        (RDC.DISPLAY_ORDER = 1 OR RDC.DISPLAY_ORDER = 2) AND
        (RDC.HAS_ALL_PERMISSION = 'Y' OR
        (CCDCR.COST_CENTRE_ID IS NOT NULL AND DDCR.DEPARTMENT_ID IS NOT NULL));
```

Query_2:

```
SELECT
        RSAL.SALE_JOURNAL_ID,
        RS.COSTING_ID,
        RD.DEBTOR_CODE,
        CONCAT('B.',LPAD(CAST(RB.BOOKING_ID AS CHAR),10,'0')) AS BOOKING_REFERENCE,
        RS.SEGMENT_ID,
        DOC.DOCUMENT_REF_NUMBER AS INVOICE_NO,
        RCON.NAME AS CONSULTANT_NAME,
        COALESCE(RSPS.LEAD_PASSENGER_NAME, RCL.PROFILE_NAME) AS COSTING_PASSENGER,
        RBR.CODE AS BRANCH_CODE,
        RS.SEGMENT_SHORT_CODE,
        (CASE WHEN RS.IDT_NUMBER = 1 THEN
            'D'
            WHEN RS.IDT_NUMBER = 2 THEN
            'T'
            WHEN RS.IDT_NUMBER = 3 THEN
            'I'
            ELSE NULL
            END) AS DOM_INT,

        (CASE WHEN RSAL.COSTING_PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE = 'PAY_DIRECT' THEN 0 ELSE 
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_EXCL_GST +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_GST_FREE +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_CHARGES_EXCL_COMMISSION +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_CHARGES_COMMISSION_FREE +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_FEES_EXCL_GST +
            RSAL.TAX_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED +
            RSAL.TAX_AMOUNT_GST_FREE +
            RSAL.AGENCY_MARKUP_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED +
            RSAL.AGENCY_DISCOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED
        END) AS GROSS_SALES,

        (CASE WHEN RSAL.COSTING_PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE = 'PAY_DIRECT' THEN 
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_EXCL_GST +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_GST_FREE +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_CHARGES_EXCL_COMMISSION +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_CHARGES_COMMISSION_FREE +
            RSAL.SUPPLIER_FEES_EXCL_GST +
            RSAL.TAX_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED +
            RSAL.TAX_AMOUNT_GST_FREE +
            RSAL.AGENCY_MARKUP_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED +
            RSAL.AGENCY_DISCOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED
        ELSE 0 END) AS PD_SALES,

        (CASE WHEN RSAL.COSTING_PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE = 'PAY_DIRECT' THEN 0 ELSE RSAL.SERVICES_CREDITOR_COMMISSION_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED - (RS.COSTING_MERCHANT_FEE_POSTED_EXCL_GST * (SIGN(RSAL.SERVICES_CREDITOR_COMMISSION_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED + RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_EXCL_GST))) END) AS EARNED_COMM,
        (CASE WHEN RSAL.COSTING_PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE = 'PAY_DIRECT' THEN RSAL.SERVICES_CREDITOR_COMMISSION_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED - (RS.COSTING_MERCHANT_FEE_POSTED_EXCL_GST * (SIGN(RSAL.SERVICES_CREDITOR_COMMISSION_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED + RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_EXCL_GST))) ELSE 0 END) AS PD_COMM,
        RSAL.OVERRIDE_AMOUNT_POSTED_EXCL_GST AS OVERRIDE_COMM,

        (CASE
            WHEN RDMF.DEBTOR_MANAGEMENT_FEE_ID IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN RDMF.FEE_AMOUNT_TYPE = 'PERCENTAGE' 
            THEN 
                (RDMF.FEE_AMOUNT / 100.00) * 
                (RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_EXCL_GST +
                RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_GST_FREE +
                RSAL.SUPPLIER_CHARGES_EXCL_COMMISSION +
                RSAL.SUPPLIER_CHARGES_COMMISSION_FREE)
            WHEN RDMF.FEE_AMOUNT_TYPE = 'DOLLAR_INCL_GST'
            THEN (RDMF.FEE_AMOUNT / ((100.00 + RAGN.GST_PERCENTAGE) / 100.00))
            ELSE
                RDMF.FEE_AMOUNT
        END) AS RETENTIONS,

        (RS.COSTING_SPECULATIVE_MERCHANT_FEE_POSTED_EXCL_GST * SIGN(RSAL.SERVICES_CREDITOR_COMMISSION_AMOUNT_EXCL_GST_CALCULATED + RSAL.SUPPLIER_RATES_EXCL_GST)) AS MERCHANT_FEE,

        CONS.NAME AS BDM1_NAME,
        RDC.COMMISSION_PERCENTAGE AS BDM1_PERCENTAGE,
        CONS2.NAME AS BDM2_NAME,
        RDC2.COMMISSION_PERCENTAGE AS BDM2_PERCENTAGE

    FROM
        TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BOOKING_$tblname TSS

        LEFT OUTER JOIN SALE_JOURNAL RSAL
            ON (RSAL.SALE_JOURNAL_ID = TSS.SALE_JOURNAL_ID)

        LEFT OUTER JOIN AGENCY RAGN
            ON (RAGN.AGENCY_ID = 1)

        LEFT OUTER JOIN TMPRPT_STBDEX_SEGMENT_$tblname RS
            ON (RS.COSTING_ID = RSAL.COSTING_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOKING RB
            ON (RB.BOOKING_ID = RS.BOOKING_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DEBTOR RD
            ON (RD.DEBTOR_ID = RB.DEBTOR_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TRANSACTION_JOURNAL RTJ
            ON (RTJ.TRANSACTION_JOURNAL_ID = RSAL.TRANSACTION_JOURNAL_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TRANSACTION_JOURNAL_LINKS TJL
            ON (TJL.TRANSACTION_JOURNAL_ID = RTJ.TRANSACTION_JOURNAL_ID)    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN INVOICE RI
            ON (RI.INVOICE_ID = TJL.INVOICE_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DOCUMENT DOC 
            ON (RI.DOCUMENT_ID = DOC.DOCUMENT_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CONSULTANT RCON
            ON (RCON.CONSULTANT_ID = RB.PREF_CONSULTANT1_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN SEGMENT_PASSENGER_SUMMARY RSPS
            ON (RSPS.SEGMENT_ID = RS.SEGMENT_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BRANCH RBR
            ON (RBR.BRANCH_ID = RB.LVL1_BRANCH_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT RCL
            ON (RCL.CLIENT_ID = RB.CLIENT_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DEBTOR_MANAGEMENT_FEE RDMF
            ON (RDMF.DEBTOR_ID = RD.DEBTOR_ID AND
                RDMF.SEGMENT_TYPE = RS.SEGMENT_TYPE_CODE AND
                (RDMF.AIRLINE_CODE = RS.AIR_AIRLINE_CODE OR RDMF.SEGMENT_TYPE <> 'TICKET') AND
                (RDMF.INT_DOM = CASE WHEN RS.IDT_NUMBER = 1 THEN 'DOMESTIC' ELSE 'INTERNATIONAL' END) AND
                (RDMF.TERMINATION_DATE IS NULL OR RDMF.TERMINATION_DATE > CURDATE()))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BDM_$tblname TSSB
            ON (TSSB.SALE_JOURNAL_ID = RSAL.SALE_JOURNAL_ID AND TSSB.DISPLAY_ORDER = 1) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP RDC
            ON (RDC.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID = TSSB.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID AND
                (RDC.CONSULTANT_ID = ParamBDMConsultant OR ParamBDMConsultant IS NULL))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CONSULTANT CONS ON (CONS.CONSULTANT_ID = RDC.CONSULTANT_ID)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BDM_$tblname TSSB2
            ON (TSSB2.SALE_JOURNAL_ID = RSAL.SALE_JOURNAL_ID AND TSSB2.DISPLAY_ORDER = 2) 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP RDC2
            ON (RDC2.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID = TSSB2.DEBTOR_CONSULTANT_RELATIONSHIP_ID AND
                (RDC2.CONSULTANT_ID = ParamBDMConsultant OR ParamBDMConsultant IS NULL))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CONSULTANT CONS2 ON (CONS2.CONSULTANT_ID = RDC2.CONSULTANT_ID)

    WHERE
        (ParamBDMConsultant IS NULL OR RDC.CONSULTANT_ID = ParamBDMConsultant) AND
        (ParamExcludeCostingsWithoutBDM = 'No' OR RDC.CONSULTANT_ID IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY 
        RSAL.SALE_JOURNAL_ID;
```

Note that **TMPRPT_STBDEX_SALE_BDM_$tblname** created in Query_1 is used twice in Query_2.

Below are the execution plans for Query_2

[Execution Plan for Query_2 when executed with in stored proc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcUHP.jpg)

[Execution Plan for Query_2 when executed manually with out stored proc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTQmR.jpg)

Note the highlighted lines where Table created in Query_1 is involved. I don't understand why it's scanning the entire table when type is *ref* and proper index is identified.

I was able to get this resolved by changing how the index is created for table in Query_1 to an *Alter table add index index_name* after the table is populated, and that solved my problem.

Also able to get this resolved by separating the data set in Query_1 into two tables and use them in place of the single table in Query_2.

For me it seemed like mysql doesn't pick the proper execution plan due to a delay in gathering stats.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Mysql version: 5.6

Comment: Because gathering stats is periodic. Building the index AFTER creating the table gets you fresh stats vs during creating the table. INstead of building the index you can also run ANALYZE TABLE after creation to make sure stats are up to date.

Comment: Thanks @Galz But shouldn't the bulk insert to the table trigger stats collection as well?

Comment: Not sure it will - specifically with `InnoDB` I had multiple issues with this, repeatedly. Today, for any table I create, insert to, and then query I use ANALYZE after insertion.